# Get substring by removing the last 3 characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to Get substring by removing the last 3 characters in javascript
I want to keep only 80000 from The string :

> 80000 km

Comment: The easier way to do it would be `yourString.substring(0, yourString.length - 3);`

Comment: This is widely covered in the Javascript documentation for String.substr() method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clip the end (right side) of the string, you can grab the substring starting from the begining and stopping three characters shy of the original length.

```js
const clipRight = (s, n) => s.substr(0, s.length - n),
      clipLeft  = (s, n) => s.substr(-n);

var str = "80000 km";

console.log(clipRight(str, 3)); // 80000
console.log(clipLeft(str, 2));  // km
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use split.

```
var x = "80000 km";

var y = x.split(" ")[0];
```

-> y is 80000

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for providing an adequate solution, however this question is blatantly off-topic. In the future, please refrain from answering these, as it encourages them to be asked in the future. While I won't downvote in this case, note that downvoting answers to off topic questions *is* the suggested action.

Comment: Oh right, this is Stack Overflow. I don't get why good answers to off-topic questions should be punished, but I'm going into off-topic territory here too.

Comment: @bdbdbd To keep it simple, StackOverflow is supposed to be a repository of useful knowledge through Q&A. Providing answers to off-topic questions encourages users to ask them again, and the end result is that the overall quality of the site's information is harmed.

Comment: @TylerRoper fair enough, thanks for the clarification!

Comment: This only works if the last 3 characters happen to be after a space, so only for the specific example in the question

Comment: @TylerRoper What makes the question off topic? It showed up in my google search, and I used the other answer